# Write a function that returns true if you can partition an array into one element and the rest, such that this element is equal to the product

Tags: java, arrays, logic

```
package ArrayPractice;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question7 {

    public boolean canPartition(int[] data) {
        Arrays.sort(data);
        int i = data[data.length - 1];
        System.out.println(i);
        int x = 1;
        int v = 1;
        for (int y = 0; y <= data.length - 2; y++) {
            x = data[y];
            v *= x;
        }
        if (v == i) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the array range: ");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int[] testing = new int[x];
        for (int y = 0; y < testing.length; y++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the Array number: " + y);
            testing[y] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        Question7 question7 = new Question7();
        System.out.println(question7.canPartition(testing));
    }
}
```

Write a function that returns true if you can partition an array into one element and the rest,
such that this element is equal to the product of all other elements excluding itself.

```
canPartition([2, 8, 4, 1]) ➞ true
8 = 2 x 4 x 1

canPartition([-1, -10, 1, -2, 20]) ➞ false

canPartition([-1, -20, 5, -1, -2, 2]) ➞ true
```

My program is working for positive values but it got failed for negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least you can do this with two nested loops and compare each item to the product of the rest:

```java
private static boolean canPartition(int[] data) {
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        int prd = 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            if (j == i) continue;              
            prd *= data[j];
        }
        if (prd == data[i]) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That's not a case for this code.

canPartition([-1, -10, 1, -2, 20]) ➞ false
canPartition([-1, -20, 5, -1, -2, 2]) ➞ true

Comment: @Maninder,  check out and run [this fiddle](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/ISG3hRJ). It prints out `false` for  `[-1, -10, 1, -2, 20]` and `true` for `[-1, -20, 5, -1, -2, 2]`.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer (✔).

Comment: I have a object list like below:
1,"test",2,"m"
need to return a new array without the strings.
I just need only integer numbers do you know how can I get?

Comment: You should write a separate question about it. Btw, you should accept [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69004175/2158271). It's the same code than in [the fiddle](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/ISG3hRJ).

Comment: Where is the option to accept your answer? Actually I am new here and don't have enough knowledge to use this website

Comment: Click the tick (✔) on the left side of the answer.  See the screenshot [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/2158271). You can also upvote the answer by clicking the up arrow above the tick.